# How to facilitate communication between different web application?

Tags: javascript, python, django, database

im trying to link up 2 different projects. I wish to be able to send out a key information to the other existing webapplication , which will then be captured in the other project's database , and the programme will then regenerate a key which will be synced back into my system to be displayed. The first programme is done using python django , and the second project is done using c# , is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is some of my code:

```
class SalesProject(models.Model):
sales_status= (
    ('p1','Phase 1'),
    ('p2','Phase 2'),
    ('p3','Phase 3'),
    ('p4','Phase 4'),
)
type_of_sales = (
('nc','non-commodities'),
('co','Commodities')
)

status = (
    ('active', 'Active'),
    ('completed', 'Completed'),
    ('inactive', 'Inactive')
)
sales_project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
sales_project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
salesExtra = models.ManyToManyField('SalesExtra', blank=True)
customer_information = models.ManyToManyField('CustomerInformation')
sales_project_status = models.CharField(max_length = 10 , default = 'p1', choices = sales_status)
sales_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10 , choices = type_of_sales)
sales_project_starting_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
sales_project_closing_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
moq = models.IntegerField(default=50)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = status, default = 'active')
quotation_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=Null)
```

The whole idea is to use the django rest framework and ajax . An instance will be created using a form that will lock in key information. This information is then fed into a django-rest api . On the other end(within the existing c# webapplication) , i will then utilize ajax detect and extract new inputs into its database system. A few calculations will be done and a new ID , quotation ID will be generated. Using AJAX POST function , i will then change the value of the quotation_ID into a unique ID number , say #1100021.

The problem with this is that the existing application has its own database structure.Certain information like user , customer information are structured differently on the django and c# programme. Therefore the c# programme cannot associate the user , customer and salesproject models to the quotation ID

.Is there a way for me to accomplish the same thing that allows me to overcome this issue?

Comment: I don't understand what your 'problem' is? The database structure is (should be) independent of the shared interface (REST API).

Comment: Yes i apologise for not being clear , the problem is , my django application needs to pass on certain information like user information , customer information , in order for the c# application to know which 'project' it is creating a quotation for , by who and for who, and successfully return a new quotation ID back.Therefore somehow there must be a way to link the two database together (or maybe there isn't but i do not know how). It currently has its own database structure , and therefore the primary keys used by the 2 applications are different , i cant assign them easily

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't understand the directions and type of information that is shared between those two applications. One of the application is an existing software with an already defined database structure and the other is a newly implemented system? Why are the primary keys of the two database tables connected? They also should be independent. If you need to create a primary key to identify syncable data between two systems you could use an UUID.

Comment: I simplify your requirement like this: system A creates some data, this is handed over to system B which will process the data and then sends it back to system A which will update the orginal data?

Comment: yes @Frieder i apologise for the misunderstandings! Im not too familiar with the usage of UUID , how do i generate one in the django application , and the same one on the c# application simultaneously

Comment: to put it simply , the sales_project_id is the id i wish to link up with the c# programme , therefore , i can perform queries on my django backend to extract out the correct quotation ID that is tied to my sales_project_id